# Is there an easy way to blend two System.Drawing.Color values?

Tags: c#, .net, colors, gdi+

Is there an easy way to blend two `System.Drawing.Color` values? Or do I have to write my own method to take in two colors and combine them?

If I do, how might one go about that?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you're trying to do with blending, but you could look into alpha blending http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing.

Comment: Combine them how? If you mix red paint with blue paint you get purple paint, but if you look at a blue ball through red glass, the ball looks black, not purple. What kind of blending did you have in mind?

Comment: @Eric Lippert: I think it was pretty clear to everyone that he meant alpha blending. Any other type of blending is much rarer and more specialised, so he would have mentioned it explicitly.

Comment: @Timwi: It was not clear to me, so it was not clear to everyone. Perhaps it was clear to everyone but me.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I wrote a utility method for exactly this purpose. :)

```
/// <summary>Blends the specified colors together.</summary>
/// <param name="color">Color to blend onto the background color.</param>
/// <param name="backColor">Color to blend the other color onto.</param>
/// <param name="amount">How much of <paramref name="color"/> to keep,
/// “on top of” <paramref name="backColor"/>.</param>
/// <returns>The blended colors.</returns>
public static Color Blend(this Color color, Color backColor, double amount)
{
    byte r = (byte) (color.R * amount + backColor.R * (1 - amount));
    byte g = (byte) (color.G * amount + backColor.G * (1 - amount));
    byte b = (byte) (color.B * amount + backColor.B * (1 - amount));
    return Color.FromRgb(r, g, b);
}
```

Comment: This would be interesting as an operator overload so that you could write: `Color NewColor = Color1 + Color2;` An article that deals with this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163737.aspx

Comment: You could always add in a "this" just because extensions are fun.

Comment: Depending on the colors, linear blending can darken the resulting color.

Comment: @Timwi: That's true -- an operator overload would have to use some default blending value.

Comment: What's about the alpha value?

Comment: ^ Alpha blending is a better method. That being said, nice extension method.

Comment: @Phillip Schmidt - This formula looks a lot like the original formula on wiki. I'm not good at reading these formulas, so I'm wondering: is there a difference?

Comment: Nice one. I only think the 'amount' value works backwards in my opinion ;) when I read color.Blend(target, 0.9) I would expect barely any of the original color left

Answer (score 7):

If you want to blend colours in a way that looks more natural to the human eye, you should consider working in a different colour space to RGB, such as [L*a*b*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space), HSL, HSB.

There a great [code project article on colour spaces](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19045/Manipulating-colors-in-NET-Part-1) with examples in C#.

You may like to work with L*a*b*, as it was designed to linearise the perception of color differences and should therefore produce elegant gradients.

Answer (score 0):

I think its easier to blend an array of colors, in case you want to blend more then 2
Here is my function:

```
private Color colorBlend(List<Color> clrArr)
{   
    int r = 0;
    int g = 0;
    int b = 0;
    foreach(Color color in clrArr)
    {
        r += color.R;
        g += color.G;
        b += color.B;
    }
    r = r / clrArr.Count;
    g = g / clrArr.Count;
    b = b / clrArr.Count;
    return Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
}
```

The array must be as a List of color
Use :

```
List<Color> colorList = new List<Color>();
colorList.Add(Color.Red);
colorList.Add(Color.Blue);
picturebox.backColor = colorBlend(colorList);
```

Answer (score 0):

To combine two colors by using alpha blending the following method can be taken:

```
private const float Divisor = byte.MaxValue;

public static Color AlphaBlend(this Color backColor, Color foreColor)
{
    var fa = foreColor.A / Divisor;
    var fr = foreColor.R / Divisor;
    var fg = foreColor.G / Divisor;
    var fb = foreColor.B / Divisor;

    var ba = backColor.A / Divisor;
    var br = backColor.R / Divisor;
    var bg = backColor.G / Divisor;
    var bb = backColor.B / Divisor;

    var a = fa + ba - fa * ba;

    if (a <= 0)
        return Color.Transparent;

    var r = (fa * (1 - ba) * fr + fa * ba * fa + (1 - fa) * ba * br) / a;
    var g = (fa * (1 - ba) * fg + fa * ba * fa + (1 - fa) * ba * bg) / a;
    var b = (fa * (1 - ba) * fb + fa * ba * fa + (1 - fa) * ba * bb) / a;

    return Color.FromArgb(
        (int)(a * byte.MaxValue),
        (int)(r * byte.MaxValue),
        (int)(g * byte.MaxValue),
        (int)(b * byte.MaxValue));
}
```

Comment: Tip: Use of a decimal type here can lead to significantly worse performance for no benefit over using float or double, both of which have hardware acceleration options available to the compiler, if you use SIMD-capable containers for your color values, such as a Vector4. Even without use of SIMD-enabled types, though, float or double will have _significantly_ better performance than decimal in every case. decimal is also not atomic and therefore not thread-safe, so be careful with that, too, for values that aren't compile-time constants (such as every intermediate result in the math here).

Comment: @dodexahedron: You're completely right. Made a test by picking all _KnownColors_, take 5 different equally distributed alpha colors for each and generated all combinations of them (made up 765,625 combinations). Then I made three versions of my code above (decimal, double, float) and calculated each of them. By checking the max difference between A, R, G and B value of each calculation, the max difference was one, which can't be recognized by human eyes. So I changed the code to use _float_, cause it is faster and produces nearly the same result.

Comment: Yep. You can also make an explicit layout struct to mimic a union, and have the individual channels as bytes. That method lends itself nicely to being able to use hardware capabilities like SIMD instructions, in quite a few cases. Float is good too but of course has caveats around some values that it can't represent precisely. If you use integral types, you won't have that issue.